# Trigger insert into another table only if unique value

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a trigger function that copy row of unique values to another table on update or insert that ALMOST work.

The trigger should only insert a new row to the sample table if the number don't exist in it before. Atm. it insert a new row to the sample table with the value NULL if the number already exist in the table. I dont want it to do anything if maintbl.number = sample.nb_main

EDIT: sample table and sample data

```
CREATE TABLE schema.main(
sid SERIAL NOT NULL,
number INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT sid_pk PRIMARY KEY (sid)
)

CREATE TABLE schema.sample(
gid SERIAL NOT NULL,
nb_main INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT gid_pk PRIMARY KEY (gid)
```

Example and desired result

```
schema.main            schema.sample       
number                 nb_main             
234233                 234233
234234                 555555 
234234  
555555  
555555
```

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.update_number()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO schema.sample(
                nb_main)
    SELECT DISTINCT(maintbl.number) 
    FROM schema.maintbl
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
SELECT nb_main FROM schema.sample WHERE maintbl.number = sample.nb_main);
    RETURN NEW; 
    END;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION schema.update_number()
      OWNER TO postgres;


    CREATE TRIGGER update_number
      AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
      ON schema.maintbl
      FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.update_number();
```

I just found out that my select query is probably wrong, if I run SELECT query by itself it return one row 'NULL' but i should not?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(maintbl.number) 
    FROM schema.maintbl
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
SELECT nb_main FROM schema.sample WHERE maintbl.number = sample.nb_main);
```

Any good advice? 
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you wish to append to `schema.sample` a number that has been inserted or updated in `schema.maintbl`, right?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.update_number()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.sample WHERE number = NEW.number) = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO schema.sample(nb_main) VALUES (NEW.number);
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW; 
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think I made myself perfectly clear. The number I am referring to is like an article number that can be redundant on many rows in the main table (why I use select distinct). I want to register the article once in the sample table when one or many articles with the same article number is added to the main table. Thanks

Comment: The code I wrote already does what you need. Would you mind to show us both table definitions? Also, will be nice if you include some data example and desired results.

Comment: Sorry you were correct Christian, one of the rows in the table was left with no data which caused the trigger to insert an empty row into the sample table. Your trigger work perfectly thanks!